# How can I solve the underfull \hbox (badness 1173) in paragraph?

Tags: badness, bad-box

This message of warning appears at the line 967, which says:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Dac\u{a} $(a_{n})_{n \geq 1} \subseteq D$ este un \c{s}ir cu $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n} \in D$, atunci $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_{n}) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n})$, adic\u{a} o func\c{t}ie continu\u{a} comut\u{a} cu limite de \c{s}iruri.
\end{enumerate}
```

In the log file:
 `underfull \hbox (badness 1173) in paragraph`

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You shoild always provide a MWE, (minimal Working Example), a small but complete document which we can test as it is.Your warning  depends from your document layout. It is defined by your document preamble, which you hide from us.

Comment: it's not an error just warning you that that line has too much white space, either ignore it or change the wording slightly.

Comment: no WHY CANT I DOWNVOTE